# Phpfox load modules content via AJAX

Tags: phpfox

i set my own template and now i want to load a module to the main content div. In the main template file there is this tag {content}. If i browse through my page into this all modules Content is loaded.

Now i want load a module manualy to this div by ajax. So if i click on a Link i want to load it. Somethink like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#change").click(function() {
        $("#content").load('module/mymodule/template/myfile.html.php');
    });
});
```

But i want to load the whole module not only a template file.

What must i do?

**Or maybe it is possible to load a Block into this div. I think this is a better solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a block file within a template then you have to use : `{module name="feed.comment"}` this code will call comment block of feed module.